# PayPal subscription api has stopped working

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

My site has been creating subscription payments for years using the classic form-post method to PayPal's cgi-bin/webscr URL.

Suddenly this has stopped working. The webscr page is called but just displays blank. Is something broken, or have PayPal changed something? There's no info to suggest the API is deprecated or anything.

I tried the "create a button" method, and using the generated html (which also calls webscr) it works. I can't use this live because some of the parameters are calculated by JS on my page, a standard button is too simplistic.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: As a followup (I posted this as a separate topic but it was queried as not being a tech question) ...

Does anyone know how to get in contact with a person at PayPal tech. support? I've had contact with them before when setting up a page to use an API. The API has stopped working (after several years), and I can't work out why. "Contact us" on PayPal now just goes round in circles offering canned answers - hopeless.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To round this off, I have discovered the cause, and it's ultimately mea culpa. I went through my code with a fine tooth comb, and for some reason the following line appeared twice in my button form html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
```

Probably an ancient copy-paste error. This never caused any problem until recently, but obviously there's been some tightening of validation by PayPal.

Removing the duplicate line has restored the original functionality.
Sometimes the simplest things can be the hardest to find!